# A hint to a problem for convergence in probability: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{\log(k)} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like a hint to show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{\log(k)} = 0 .
$$

Comment: This looks like Calc I, and self study.  Sandwich theorem should work.  [link](http://searchonmath.com/result?equation=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D+%5Csum_%7Bi%3D2%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B+%5Cln%7Bk%7D+%7D+%7D&page=1&tm=1)

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following fact (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1957849/23249) for the proof).

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, then
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=a,
> $$
>   where $(c_n)$ is the sequence of the [Cesàro means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) of the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by
>   $$
> c_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i
> $$
>   for each $n\ge1$.

Hence, we need to show that
$$
\frac1{\log n}\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: How do you do that last bit? Using the Sandwich Theorem, I'm assuming?

Comment: @SkeletonBow One way to do that is to show that $\log n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Choose $M>0$. Then we have that $\log n>M$ for each $n>e^M$.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).